# Laravel 5.4 file upload

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.4 and want to upload image.
But in controllrt $request->hasFile('pic') returns false.
This is my blade.php :

```
.
.
.
<form action="{{ route('my-url') }}" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="pic">
</form>
.
.
.
```

And this is my controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class myclass extends Controller {

    public function myfunc(Request $request) {
        if($request->hasFile('pic')){
            // never get this
        }
    }
}
```

Should i add another field to form or input in blade.php or controller?

Comment: When using files you need to include the encryption type, add this to your form: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

The form data being encoded as `“multipart/form-data”`, which is required when files will be included as form data.

```
<form action="{{ route('my-url') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="pic">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 just addd in your form
 <form action="{{ route('my-url') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="pic">
</form>
//enctype="multipart/form-data" add this, this will your
```